# Genetic Programming with the Mandelbrot Set

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-programming, fractals, complex-numbers, mandelbrot

I'm reading a chapter in this fascinating [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558606734) about using genetic programming to interactively evolve images. Most of the function set is comprised of simple arithmetic and trig functions (which really operation on and return images). These functions make up the internal nodes of the parse trees that encode our images. The leaves of the tree, or the terminal values, are random numbers and x,y coordinates.

There's a section about adding iterative functions of the complex plane to the function set:

> Say the genetics inserts a particular Mandelbrot set as a node somewhere in
>   a bushy tree. The function expects two arguments: mandel(cReal, cImag), treating
>   them as real and imaginary coordinates in the complex plane. If the genome
>   just happened to supply the pixel coordinates (x,y), and mandel() were the root
>   node, you would get the familiar Mset. But chances are that cReal and cImag are themselves the results of whole branches of functions, with many instances of coordinates
>   x,y scattered out among the leaves. Enter the iteration loop, orbit
>   around for a while, and finally escape with some measure of distance to the Mset
>   attractor, such as the number of iterations.

My question is how would you make a Mandelbrot set renderer as a function that takes the real and imaginary coordinates of a point on the complex plane as arguments and returns a rendering of the Mandelbrot set?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this actually answers your question, but my understanding of the text you quoted simply says that the `mandel` function *is just another function* (like multiplication, min, max, addition, etc) that can appear in your genetic program.

The `mandel` function, like the multiplication function, takes two arguments (`in_1` and `in_2`) and returns a single value.  Whereas the multiplication function just returns `in_1 * in_2`, the mandel function might do [something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#For_programmers):

```
int mandel(int in_1, int in_2) {
  x = 0
  y = 0
  iteration = 0
  max_iteration = 1000

  while( x*x + y*y <= (2*2) && iteration < max_iteration ) {
    xtemp = x*x - y*y + in_1
    y = 2*x*y + in_2
    x = xtemp

    ++iteration
  }

  if( iteration == max_iteration ) return 0
  else return iteration
}
```

If your whole genetic program tree consists of nothing but the `mandel` function with one input as `x` and the other input as `y`, then repeatedly evaluating your program for a bunch of different `(x,y)` values and saving the result will give you a nice picture of the Mandelbrot set.

Of course, the neat thing about genetic programming is that the inputs can be fancier than just `x` and `y`.  For example, what would the result look like if one input was `x` and the other input was `x + 2*y`?  Or if one input was `x` and the other was `mandel(x,y)`?